# Secure Spring Cloud Gateway routing for microservice with mixed mTLS and Bearer token authentication

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway, mtls

I have a microservice named "Books," featuring a secure GET /books endpoint utilizing mTLS for authentication. Our next step involves integrating this microservice into a Spring Cloud Gateway. Our ultimate objective is to enhance security by requiring a bearer token for access via the gateway, while still maintaining the mTLS based security between the gateway and the Books microservice. Is it possible to achieve this configuration without applying mTLS directly to the GET /books route of the Spring Cloud Gateway? If so, what approach should be taken to implement this mixed authentication setup effectively?

Below diagram demonstrate the highlevel architecture.

[image]